# How to build $n$-categories and $n$-functors from the basics

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, higher-category-theory

How do I build [$n$-categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/n-category) and [$n$-functors](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/n-functor), starting from a $0$-category and a $0$-functor?

> We can take examples, focusing on $n=2$. And we state clearly what kinds of $m$-morphisms are allowed.

Here are some basics we can start with:

- A 0-category is a set.
- A 1-category is an ordinary category.
- A 2-category is (depending on how strict was your initial notion of $\infty$-category) either a strict 2-category or a bicategory.
- A $n$-functor is a functor between $n$-categories.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: I mean, there's the fact that a strict $(n+1)$-category is simply a category enriched in strict $n$-categories, but other than that I too am nonplussed by what you say here.

Comment: That's an open problem.